# нужен совет по регистрация пользователя

Tags: веб-программирование

Я делаю пет проект, где хочу реализовать регистрацию пользователя, хотел бы спросить совет у более опытных людей.

**Задача:**

Зарегистрировать пользователя со следующими полями:

1. username[str, unique]
2. email[str, unique],
3. is_active [bool] = default
4. password[str]
5. created_at[datetime]

Я хочу отправлять пользователю уникальную ссылку на email, после перехода по которой is_active станет True.

Итак, вопрос если кто-то начнет регать всем аккаунты при этом не подтверждая их. Появляются следующие проблемы:

1. Заспамленность БД "Мертвыми душами".
2. Реальный пользователь не сможет зарегаться, если его email введут таким образом.

**Решение, которое пришло в голову**

Можно раз в какой-то интервал удалять всех пользователей у кого например `now() - created_at > 1 hour`.

Минус этого решения придется дергать БД, если много записей в БД, то будет не очень хорошо.

Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: есть уже готовые решения, нужно сузить нам круг поиска. В django данное решение идет "из коробоки", например. Так что вы определите какой ЯП, какой фреймворк и смотрите, что уже есть. А вот если в учебных целях, тогда вопрос все равно надо сузить до конкретной задачи

Comment: @Dmitry Я пишу на python, Использую FastApi. Это в учебных целях

Comment: Создавать аккаунт только после перехода по ссылке из email

Comment: Мне не нравится django. Мне кажется она слишком много на себя берет)

Comment: @andreymal а где хранить информацию о пользователе в другой таблице? или в key-value хранилище ?

Comment: @nicholas сами выбирайте что вам удобнее

Comment: @andreymal github создает аккаунт до подверждения, я проверял)

Comment: @nicholas ну и зря

Comment: Я не пропагандирую в фреймворк, я к тому, что уже существует реализация, можно подсмотреть и реализовать

Comment: @Dmitry да вы правы, пожалуй так и сделаю)